# Changing the placeholder text of a login screen

Tags: javascript, input, field, placeholder

The landing page of our LMS:
https://rainforrentlms.litmos.com/account/Login

We want to use the custom CSS option or the custom Javascript option in our LMS's theme setup screen to adjust the placeholder text from **Username** to **Employee Number**.

When I inspect the element this is what I extract:

```html
<input class="first-focus form-control input-lg" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="true" type="text" value="">
```

After reading many posts here on StackOverflow I surmised that I should use Javascript as we've used that successfully to tweak other things in the past.

Here is an existing snippet that is already in our LMS's custom Javascript box:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 checkContainer();
});
function checkContainer () {
 if($('#SendEmail').is(':visible')){ //if the container is visible on the page
 $("#SendEmail").attr('checked', false); //Un-checks the checkbox using CSS ID
 } else {
 setTimeout(checkContainer, 50); //wait 50 ms, then try again
 }
}
</script>
```

The code I guessed would work and need to be inserted:

```js
$('Username').attr('placeholder','Employee Number');
```

I'm not sure if that's correct, I've tried adding that at the top just inside the header and I've tried inserting it all by itself after removing the other code temporarily, neither seems to be working.

=========EDIT #1===========
So here is the code I tried using your suggestion for putting it in the document ready section, also didn't have any effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#Username').attr('placeholder','Employee Number');
 checkContainer();
});
function checkContainer () {
 if($('#SendEmail').is(':visible')){ //if the container is visible on the page
 $("#SendEmail").attr('checked', false); //Un-checks the checkbox using CSS ID
 } else {
 setTimeout(checkContainer, 50); //wait 50 ms, then try again
 }
}
$('#Username').attr('placeholder','Employee Number');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Username').attr('placeholder','Employee Number');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `#` before `Username`, so it should be:

```
$('#Username').attr('placeholder','Employee Number');
```

The `#` tells jQuery to look for an element with `id="Username"`, as opposed to a `<Username>` element.

Comment: That's great, I've tried removing the existing script (noted previously above) that is working and replacing it with just  inline `<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Username').attr('placeholder','Employee Number');
</script>`
  Unfortunately it's not working at all, checked multiple browsers.

Comment: I also tried leaving in the original javascript from above and adding my three lines below as a new section, didn't work.

Comment: I've also tried putting JUST the line of code you've provided at the top just below script type= line, didn't work.  Then I tried adding it just at the bottom above the /script, no dice.

Comment: I can't quite picture what your code looks like. Could you edit your question to include it?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: `$('#Username').attr('placeholder','Employee Number');`

Comment: `</script>`      .like those 3 lines.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried putting it in your `$(document).ready` handler instead?

Comment: I added the code I tried using your suggestion document.ready in post #1, it didn't work either.  I do appreciate you're coaxing me along.

Comment: Interesting. Your code looks fine to me. I tried running the line in the JavaScript console on the page, and it worked fine, so the problem is something to do with when it's being run. Beyond that I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: I concur, I dropped it in the console and instantly see what we want.  I've contacted the LMS developer and asked them to review their "Custom Javascript" panel they provide for us to put these things into, hopefully they can advise why it isn't triggering.  Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The LMS has confirmed that JS on the login page is not allowed, that is why it isn't working.  Ugh.